# Tooltip of AngularUI not shown for divs within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm trying to show a tooltip on some divs of a website using AngularUI. The goal is to show them already when the user enters the site. That's why `tooltop-is-open` is set to `true`. However, this does not work for elements within a repeating group (i.e. divs created via `ng-repeat`). What am I missing?

Here is the HTML:

```js
<script >
angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('testApp')
.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.demo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

}]);
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="testApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="testController" >

        <!-- works -->
        <div >
            <h1 uib-tooltip="hallo" 
             tooltip-is-open="true" 
             tooltip-placement="bottom">Title</h1>
        </div>

        <!-- does not work -->        
        <div ng-repeat="a in demo">
            <h2 uib-tooltip="hallo"
                 tooltip-is-open="true" 
                 tooltip-placement="bottom">{{ a }}</h2>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me, here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4Gd1b9CCpzdrIIJoOw3?p=preview)

Comment: @PankajParkar no its not working, because the tooltips should be shown immediately, not after hovering

Comment: @devqon Thanks for heads up sir, I totally misreaded question

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the `uib-tooltip`, because when you do a timeout, it does work: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TnCRCdAumhuFpqPVapT7?p=preview)

Comment: @devqon Wiered, any guess why it got worked?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the digest cycle sequence

Comment: I tried the suggestion from @KScandrett using `uib-tooltip-html`. In the plunkr from @PankajPakar it works. But locally the tooltips are showing up but are empty. Funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `uib-tooltip-html` inside the ngRepeat instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in demo">
    <h2 uib-tooltip-html="'hallo'" tooltip-is-open="true" tooltip-placement="bottom">
        {{ a }}
    </h2>
</div>
```

Looks like a bug

Comment: Don't forget the inner quotes around the Tooltip contents

Comment: Funny. In the plunkr provided by @PankajParkar above it works. But locally it doesn't. I double checked that I have the quotes set.

Comment: I accept this answer as it seems to be the best solution yet. Still, it looks like there is at least one bug.

Comment: Opened an issue for that at [angular-ui/bootstrap on GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6307)